# Android Change ToggleButton in Another Fragment

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to change a `ToggleButton` in another fragment (Using `TabLayout`)?  I have a ToggleButton on my main `Fragment` and when I change that button, I would like to change the button in the other `Fragment`.

Comment: You could use `LocalBroadCastManager`.

Comment: Would I create an `Intent` to start the `Fragment` I want updated, then broadcast it using `LocalBroasdcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);`?

Comment: This will help :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager